# How to build a square with a star

Tags: geometry

I have a problem that I can't solve. It says:

"If you rotate a square 45º you get a 8-pointed star. Prove that you can divide that star in 8 parts with which you can build a new square"

I have calculated that if the original side of the square was 1, the new side is $\sqrt{4-2\sqrt2}$, and I don't know how I can do a division to obtain this side.
Any suggestion? 
Thanks!

---

Thanks you very much. 
I haven't solved the problem yet, but I have done more steps:
In Moti's picture, the segment IJ has lenght $\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{2}}$ as we want. This triangle is rectangle in F so the angles FIJ, IJF are supplementary. With 4 triangles like that we can build a square with side IJ, but in the middle we obtain a new empty square with side $\sqrt 2 /2 $ (and diagonal 1). But I don't know how to do the partition.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks as though you get that edge length as the length of the segment between two opposite concave vertices. So cutting the star in half along such a cut might be a good first step. I still have trouble with some of the smaller pieces, though.

Comment: The original square may be divided into 4 shapes of which the laager square may be structured in which the four additional triangles will fit. Let me know if you need help...

Comment: Thanks you very much Moti, but I'm still having problems. With the 4 additional triangles I'm building a new square with side $\sqrt 2 - 1 $ and I'm trying to divide the original square in triangles like FIJ...

Answer (score 2):

The following picture should serve as a very close to solution hint.

[image]